# Cannot create SSRS subscription for a report using SSAS as datasource

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, ssas

My questions is : how should I config SSRS subscription a report, which consumes SSAS datasource.
I already googled and lookup stackoverflow a lot and still couldn't make it work.

Problems:
I developed and deployed a SSRS report to the server, and next I need to make subscription for that report to send emails.

And the report is using SSAS as datasource. 
I learnt that SSAS required to use windows credentials and I already setup 
the datasource .
 [image: Datasource tested]
However, when I attempted to click [New subscription], it alerts:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have blogged about this exact issue. The workaround/solution involves expression-based connection strings which can be a bit painful. But I have prototyped a tool to automate the setup of those connection strings after deployment:

[Using EffectiveUserName To Impersonate in SSAS](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2010/4/1/using-effectiveusername-to-impersonate-in-ssas)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my steps to resolve the problem by following GregGalloway's blog.

1 create a parameter called username, and give it a default user name.[image][image]

2 Edit the datasource and click [Fx] to create a expression as the connection string.[image]

3. Key in the following as the value of [Fx], please note that Parameters!**username**.Value which [username] is the parameter name created in #1

   ="Data Source=[your ssas server ip];Initial Catalog=[your ssas catalog name];EffectiveUserName=" & Parameters!**username**.Value
4. Deploy the report.
5. Open the report on the server on the drop down menu click [Manage], then open data source, 
   -turn on [credentials stored securely.....]
   -key in [user name] , [Password], 
   -Turn on [Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the datasource.
   [image]

   [image]

   6. Finally create subscription

   [image: List item]

Answer (score -3):

in the report it self, inside "data source" use SQL credential :

[image]

Comment: How would SQL authentication work with SSAS?